# Wild Card and Batch movile files (Windows)

Tags: batch-file

I am needing some help with batch moves. Here is the scenario. I have two folders:

> C:\Test1
> C:\Test2

In `C:\Test1` there are multiple files with names that have the same prefix such as:

> test1
> Test2
> Test3
> Test4
> Batch1
> Batch2
> Batch3
> Sched1
> Sched2
> Sched3
> …etc.

I need to be able to copy and move multiple files to another directory in batch. An example of what I am trying to do "which does not work" is

```
copy C:\Test1\Test*.txt c:\Test2\
```

*The idea would be that all files that start with Test would be moved to the second directory `C:\Test2\`*

How can I accomplish this? Any ideas would be swell. Or if you have any questions please feel free to ask me so

Comment: if you want to move them, use the [move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) command instead of `copy`...

Comment: Assuming the files actually have the extension `.txt` but you've not shown this (=bad -- make the question clear), can you expand on "which does not work" (=also bad -- always show error messages and/or explain what it did do and what you expected it to) because it should (in that it should copy the files, not move them, as Stephan says).

Comment: Personally, if I wanted to copy files that matched a pattern, I'd be awfully tempted to use `xcopy`